# How to solve response code 500 in cytargetlinker?

Tags: cytoscape

Got a problem when I followed the tutorial 1 in cyTargetlinker. Every step is smooth until I reached step 4 after I selected "2" for the "overlap threshold" functionality. It gave a sign "Caught exception executing task" with a statement "Untitled (org.cytargetlinker.app.internal.tasks.FilterOverlapTask). I further checked the automation and it stated that there was an error 500 response code. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

I download Cytoscape 3.8.0 and intalled cyTargetLinker app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An error 500 indicates a problem with the CyTargetLinker web service.  I know that some of the web sites at Maastricht have been offline due to a recent hack, but I don't know if that's the problem.  You might try e-mailing the App authors (go to http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/cytargetlinker and click on e-mail).

-- scooter